# help with translation of a sentence

Tags: перевод

Привет!

What is the meaning of this sentence?

какие планы при выигрыше?

I'm not sure about the use of the preposition при. Is it 'what are your plans *if* you win', or 'what are your plans *in order to* win'?

Comment: The first one, "what are your plans **if** you win".

Comment: generally speaking, it is not correct to translate the sentence to *what are **your** plans if **you** win*. There is no mention about **you** in the Russian variant. There in only a mention of a win without specifying whose one. So the correct version would be *what are the plans in case of a win* or *what are the plans if there is a win*

Comment: I see, thanks for all the answers! Yes, there is no subject in the Russian sentence, I think it's implied for someone who knows the context.